# Blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource Error In Socket.io Error How to Resolve?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I am facing issue in socket.io (Version Socket.IO v2.3.0).When i request from subdomain to main domain using socket.io it gives an error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://testing.api.xyzdomain.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NeQKGfD' from origin 'https://testing.xyzdomain.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Here is my socket.io code:

```js
window.socket_url = 'https://testing.api.xyzdomain.com'
var socket = io.connect(window.socket_url);

socket.emit('joinCommonUserRoom', `room_${window.room}_${getUserDetails().id}_USER`);

socket.on('socketStatus', function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});

socket.on('newRequest', function(data) {
  ongoing();
});

ongoing();
```

Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

Comment: You need to add CORS headers to the response from the main domain to enable the subdomain (and ***only*** the subdomain) to make requests to it. Exactly how you do that will depend on what server platform you're using, but in any case Google will help you there.

Comment: assuming that the server is using socket.io and you have control over it... https://socket.io/docs/v4/handling-cors/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your are missing the cors, for further details you can see [CORS IN SOCKET.IO](https://socket.io/docs/v4/handling-cors/)

```
var socket = io.connect(window.socket_url,{
 cors:{
    origin:'*',
    credentials:true
 }
});
```